# Generating number orbitals in C

Tags: c

So, I was making a program that generates orbitals of a specific function where I have to present a 3 functions:

k function that stores the position of the first number that is repeated.
p function that stores the number of times the first repeated number takes to repeat itself.
q function that holds an id for a sequence of numbers

I was successful in generating the orbits, making the k and p function but, I'm stuck on how to do the q function.

assuming the initial function contains these elements: `f = {3,1,2,5,4,3,8,8,8,1,12,4}`

generating orbits from f, we get a matrix like this:

[image]

the first column: 1 - 12 is the index,
the second column is the function f, and then the following orbits

Following the matrix, the k function would be: `k  = {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,2,1}`
the function p = `{3,3,3,2,2,3,1,1,1,3,2,2}`
Assuming that

`id 1 = 3-2-1 id 2 = 4-5 id 3 = 8-8`
we will have the q function :  `q  = {1,1,1,2,2,1,3,3,3,1,2,2}`

My question is: how do I program the q function?

Comment: I think it's high time mathematicians got creative and started to come up with new words for new concepts. Whoever decided to call this an "orbital" has cleverly failed at basic scientific communication :(

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I expected to find something related to Kepler in the question.